# How to call array from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to call array but still failed.
Here is my JS

```
var dataLayer =
[
    {
        "id" : "993932",
        "name" : "Foo Bar",
        "total_price" : "867252",
        "Recommended" : 
        [
            {
                "hotel_name" : "Four Season",
                "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
            },
            {
                 "hotel_name" : "Amaris Hotel",
                 "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
            }
        ];

var a = "<div>"+ dataLayer.hotel_name +"</div>"
```

or you can check in https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/7fnzofg1/1/

The result is **undefined**. Anyone to help me? 
Thank you

Comment: Your `dataLayer` array is not valid. You're missing closing braces/brackets. If you add those, you could do e.g. `dataLayer[0].Recommended[0].hotel_name`

Comment: I've "fixed" your code indention. You can see the problem for yourself now.

Comment: Hi @icecub thank you, it works. yes something wrong in my code before. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `datalayer` is an array of object and the key `Recommended` is also an array of object so to access them you need to first select the element in the index.

`dataLayer[0]` will fetch the first object in your array which is the only one in your case

```
{
        "id" : "993932",
        "name" : "Foo Bar",
        "total_price" : "867252",
        "Recommended" : [
         {
            "hotel_name" : "Four Season",
            "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
         },
         {
             "hotel_name" : "Amaris Hotel",
             "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
         }
         ]
    }
```

then the key `Recommended` also has an array of object

```
[
     {
        "hotel_name" : "Four Season",
        "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
     },
     {
         "hotel_name" : "Amaris Hotel",
         "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
     }
 ]
```

so, you need to access them using index.

`dataLayer[0].Recommended[0]` will select the first object

```
{
     "hotel_name" : "Four Season",
     "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
}
```

`dataLayer[0].Recommended[0].hotel_name` to select the key `hotel_name`

To iterate over all the objects in recommended key array you can use forEach

```
 dataLayer[0].Recommended.forEach(function(obj){
    console.log(obj.hotel_name);
  });
```

```js
var dataLayer = [
 {
    "id" : "993932",
    "name" : "Foo Bar",
    "total_price" : "867252",
    "Recommended" : [
     {
        "hotel_name" : "Four Season",
        "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
     },
     {
         "hotel_name" : "Amaris Hotel",
         "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
     }
     ]
}
];

dataLayer[0].Recommended.forEach(function(obj){
  console.log(obj.hotel_name);
});
```

Comment: Oh thank you, but how to call all hotel name? not only four season

Comment: you need to iterate over the array of objects in recommended

Comment: ohh great. Very useful thank you, that's what I need @Nadir

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var dataLayer = [
 {
    "id" : "993932",
    "name" : "Foo Bar",
    "total_price" : "867252",
    "Recommended" : [
     {
        "hotel_name" : "Four Season",
        "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
     },
     {
         "hotel_name" : "Amaris Hotel",
         "tripadvisor_ratings" : "5.0"
     }
     ]
}
];
alert(dataLayer[0].Recommended[0].hotel_name);
alert(dataLayer[0].Recommended[1].hotel_name);
```